# How to pass file server to computer that is connected by Internet connection sharing?

Tags: networking, router, internet

I need access to my file server from a desktop I have connected through Internet Connection Sharing. I am using Internet connection sharing because the netgear router doesn't have enough plugs. The file server is setup to be access from //fileserver , but Internet connection sharing is basically its on its own network and that is why it doesn't have access to my server.  So How can I get the desktop that is connected through internet connection sharing access to //fileserver ?

Comment: Have you tried with the IP address instead of the name? What were the results? Please [edit] and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Or buy a switch?

Comment: @MichaelBay I did try that it does not work , with the internal address. It seems that when using Internet connection sharing , windows puts the computers that are connected through internet connection sharing as its own network.